# Surface pgf plot of x=f(y,z)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

With `pgfplots` a surface can easily be generated using `\addplot3` with `z=f(x,y)`.

Is there a way to generate a surface with formula `x = f(y,z)`.

I can't change the axis since I have another `\addplot3{f(x,y)}` in the code.

Comment: `\addplot3 ({f(x,y)},y,x);` or `\addplot3 ({f(x,y)},x,y);` can be used.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat How do you add domain for x & y, if I want x=0, y=0:5

Comment: Do you want `x=0` or `x=f(u,v)`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I made a mistake in my previous comment. Suppose in `\addplot3 ({f(x,y)},y,x);`  `x=0:3`, and `y=0:5`. I don;t want a parametric surface

Comment: But `\addplot3 {f(x,y)};` is the same as `\addplot3 (x,y,{f(x,y)});`, so all plots are parametric plots. The prescription `x = f(y,z)`  translates into `\addplot3 ({f(x,y)},y,x);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I meant is this: you can always use a parametric plot to swap the roles of x and z, say. For instance, if you replace

```
 \addplot3[surf,domain=0:5,domain y=0:5] {f(x,y)};
```

by

```
 \addplot3[surf,domain=0:5,domain y=0:5,point meta=x] ({f(x,y)},x,y);
```

the x amplitude is determined by the function instead of the z amplitude.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=6+exp(-pow(\x-2.5,2)-pow(\y-2.5,2));}]
 \addplot3[surf,domain=0:5,domain y=0:5] {f(x,y)};
 \addplot3[surf,domain=0:5,domain y=0:5,point meta=x] ({f(x,y)},x,y);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I had understood your point. It is just generating a mesh with specified coordinates.

Comment: Very nice example of application, cristal clear !